# SharePoint 365 online document library - stop Upload button overwriting existing files

Tags: sharepoint-online

We use SharePoint Site document libraries as a client portal and want to use the Upload button to allow users to upload documents/pictures/etc as a means of securely communicating sensitive files. However, the default behaviour of the Upload button is to to ask whether to overwrite an existing file, but we need to retain existing files. Is there anyway to alter the functionality of the Upload button to not overwrite files and simply add, say, (1)/(2)/etc to a filename instead? This is basic stuff so hopefully Microsoft have sorted this as an option?

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload documents with the same file name to the Document Library in Modern SharePoint Online, you can click "**Keep both**" button to save documents.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is aimed at the improvement of the **SharePoint Online modern experience**, so that it can better facilitate the user to manage documents.

**For example:**

1. Prevent users add the same files to the Document library to ensure the uniqueness of the document.
2. Ensure the reliability of document properties (columns). Because even if you upload the same file, the "Modified" is different every time.